# Making a animation of multiple 3D objects rotating

Tags: graphics3d, animation

I know that there is a similar question of taking an animation of 3D object, however since I'm not good at Mathematica nor English, I couldn't figure out how to make animation of multiple objects rotating. Below is the code of graphic I would like to rotate around vector {0,1,0}.

```
s[x_,y_]:=y/Sqrt[x^2+y^2];
star=RegionPlot3D[x^2+y^2<=(1-3z^2)(3+1.3(1-3z^2)(5s[x,y]-20s[x,y]^3+16s[x,y]^5))&&Abs[z]<=1,{x,-2.2,2.2},{y,-2,2.4},{z,-2,2},PlotPoints->80,PlotStyle->Directive[Yellow],Mesh->None,Axes->False,Boxed->False,ViewPoint->{-1.45,-0.175,1.6},ViewVertical->{0,1,0}];
eye1=RegionPlot3D[(x+0.41)^2/0.005+(y-0.3)^2/0.1+(z-0.52)^2/0.01<=1,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},{z,-1.8,1.8},PlotPoints->80,PlotStyle->Directive[Black,Specularity[80]]];
eye2=RegionPlot3D[(x-0.41)^2/0.005+(y-0.3)^2/0.1+(z-0.52)^2/0.01<=1,{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},{z,-1.8,1.8},PlotPoints->80,PlotStyle->Directive[Black,Specularity[80]]];
Show[star, eye1, eye2]
```

[image: This is the picture of my graphic.]
Can somebody help please..?

Comment: It would be good to provide a link to the question that you think is related.

Answer (score 13):

```
s[x_, y_] := y/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
star = RegionPlot3D[
   x^2 + y^2 <= (1 - 3 z^2) (3 + 
        1.3 (1 - 3 z^2) (5 s[x, y] - 20 s[x, y]^3 + 16 s[x, y]^5)) && 
    Abs[z] <= 1, {x, -2.2, 2.2}, {y, -2, 2.4}, {z, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 80, PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow], Mesh -> None, 
   Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {-1.45, -0.175, 1.6}, 
   ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}];
eye1 = RegionPlot3D[(x + 0.41)^2/0.005 + (y - 0.3)^2/
      0.1 + (z - 0.52)^2/0.01 <= 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -1.8, 
    1.8}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Specularity[80]]];
eye2 = RegionPlot3D[(x - 0.41)^2/0.005 + (y - 0.3)^2/
      0.1 + (z - 0.52)^2/0.01 <= 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -1.8, 
    1.8}, PlotPoints -> 80, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Specularity[80]]];
p = Show[star, eye1, eye2]

lst = Table[
   Graphics3D[Rotate[p[[1]], 2*Pi*t, {0, 1, 0}], Boxed -> False, 
    Axes -> False], {t, 0, 1, .05}];

ListAnimate[lst]
```

[image: Figure 1]